# Install rails app (locally) on new machine and getting error PG::UndefinedTable: ERROR: relation "users" does not exist

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I must be doing something wrong. 
I did the following and it worked fine:

```
rake db:drop:all
rake db:create:all
```

But as soon as I do :

```
rake db:migrate
```

I get:

```
rake aborted!
ActiveRecord::StatementInvalid: PG::UndefinedTable: ERROR:  relation "users" does not exist
LINE 5:                WHERE a.attrelid = '"users"'::regclass
                                      ^
:               SELECT a.attname, format_type(a.atttypid, a.atttypmod),
                 pg_get_expr(d.adbin, d.adrelid), a.attnotnull, a.atttypid, a.atttypmod
            FROM pg_attribute a LEFT JOIN pg_attrdef d
              ON a.attrelid = d.adrelid AND a.attnum = d.adnum
           WHERE a.attrelid = '"users"'::regclass
             AND a.attnum > 0 AND NOT a.attisdropped
           ORDER BY a.attnum
```

When I run :

```
rails db:
```

I get:

```
psql (9.4.4)
Type "help" for help.

db_development=# \d
No relations found.
```

Any ideas? I also get the same error when I run :

```
rake db:reset
```

Answer (score 1):

Try:

`rake db:migrate`

While working on a Rails project, whether you clone it from some remote repository or you create it from the scratch, the first thing you do to create the database is:

`rake db:create`

and then the relationships among the tables of your database:

`rake db:migrate`

You would run the `rake db:create` command only once in the beginning. After that, every time you add/change a migration, you should run `rake db:migrate`

To see all the available rake tasks, you could use:

`rake -T`

Comment: Hi, I get the same error when I run "rake db:migrate"

Comment: Did you create the Rails app yourself? or you cloned it from somewhere? 
Can you try from the beginning again? clone the project, then run:
1. rake db:create
2. rake db:migrate
See what happens. Let me know!
Also, let me know if I can take a look at the source code if its on github already.

Comment: Yes it still does the same error. I wrote the rails app, but it's the first time I move my development to a different machine. I ended up working around the issue by dumping my db from one machine to next.

Comment: Good to hear that you got a workaround for your problem :)

Answer (score 0):

Try running your migration to create users table

```
rake db:migrate
```

By rake db:create, you are creating a blank database but to create all the relations you have to migrate it

Answer (score 0):

Try running `rake db:migrate` to create the missing tables.

Answer (score 0):

The commando 
`rake db:create:all`
only creates the database for you. You need to run the migrations `rake db:migrate` to add tables and columns to your newly created database.

There is also a `rake db:setup` command that does:  does db:create, db:schema:load, db:seed, only works if you already have a schema.

You can take a look at [database.rake](https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/master/activerecord/lib/active_record/railties/databases.rake) to view all available commands.

Answer (score 0):

I realize this is old, but this might help.

It sounds like the error is coming from actually not having any users yet(since you've cloned the app).

You can try creating a user through the terminal or maybe to check for the user's presence (

```
<% if user.present?%>
 #then execute this code 
<% end %>
```

)